# NameError : uninitialized constant Chef::Resource::PythonPip

Tags: python, ruby, pip, chef-infra

[image]

I'm following the Mining the social media 2nd Edition book to do some data science on Twitter. I Downloaded the file containing the necessary files and folders etc ... 
While trying to vagrant up ( it uses Vagrant to control a VM ( a virtualBox vm) where some ipython notebooks will be executed  ) , I figured out a strange error: NoNameError: uninitialized constant Chef::Resource::PythonPip
Here is the default.tb file :
default['python']['install_method'] = 'package'

```
if node['python']['install_method'] == 'package'
  case node['platform']
  when "smartos"
   default['python']['prefix_dir']         = '/opt/local'
  else
    default['python']['prefix_dir']         = '/usr'
  end
else
  default['python']['prefix_dir']         = '/usr/local'
end

default['python']['binary'] = "#{node['python']
['prefix_dir']}/bin/python"

default['python']['url'] = 'http://www.python.org/ftp/python'
default['python']['version'] = '2.7.7'
default['python']['checksum'] = 
'3b477554864e616a041ee4d7cef9849751770bc7c39adaf78a94ea145c488059'
default['python']['configure_options'] = %W{--prefix=#{node['python']
['prefix_dir']}}

default['python']['setuptools_script_url'] = 
'https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/0.8/ez_setup.py'
default['python']['pip_script_url'] = 'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-
pip.py'
```

here is the /deploy/python/providers/pip.rb (where it recognized it the error)

```
require 'chef/mixin/shell_out'
require 'chef/mixin/language'
include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut

def whyrun_supported?
  true
end

# the logic in all action methods mirror that of
# the Chef::Provider::Package which will make
# refactoring into core chef easy

action :install do
  # If we specified a version, and it's not the current version, move 
to the specified version
  if new_resource.version != nil && new_resource.version != 
current_resource.version
    install_version = new_resource.version
  # If it's not installed at all, install it
  elsif current_resource.version == nil
    install_version = candidate_version
  end

  if install_version
    description = "install package #{new_resource} version #
{install_version}"
    converge_by(description) do
      Chef::Log.info("Installing #{new_resource} version #
{install_version}")
      status = install_package(install_version)
      if status
        new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
      end
    end
  end
end

action :upgrade do
  if current_resource.version != candidate_version
    orig_version = current_resource.version || "uninstalled"
    description = "upgrade #{current_resource} version from #
{current_resource.version} to #{candidate_version}"
    converge_by(description) do
      Chef::Log.info("Upgrading #{new_resource} version from #
{orig_version} to #{candidate_version}")
      status = upgrade_package(candidate_version)
      if status
        new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
      end
    end
  end
end

action :remove do
  if removing_package?
   description = "remove package #{new_resource}"
   converge_by(description) do
     Chef::Log.info("Removing #{new_resource}")
      remove_package(new_resource.version)
     new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing to poise-python is the best solution but it is possible to patch the old python cookbook. Understanding why this error happens might help others with similar issues in their custom cookbooks as they move to Chef 13.

Chef 13 no longer creates module constants for custom resources as noted in the release notes https://discourse.chef.io/t/chef-client-13-released/10735

Only two lines of code need changed in the depreciated python cookbook so it works with chef 13.

In providers/virtualenv.rb:

```
-  @current_resource = Chef::Resource::PythonVirtualenv.new(new_resource.name)
+  @current_resource = Chef::Resource.resource_for_node(:python_virtualenv, node).new(new_resource.name)
```

In providers/pip.rb:

```
-  @current_resource = Chef::Resource::PythonPip.new(new_resource.name)
+  @current_resource = ::Chef::Resource.resource_for_node(:python_pip, node).new(new_resource.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `python` cookbook is clearly marked as deprecated, and is not supported on Chef 13 at all (or just in general, but I won't be fixing it for Chef 13). Use `poise-python` instead.

Comment: can you tell me please what should I do exactly ???  Replace the python folder with the poise-python (from Git ) ??? I thought that it could be a "deprecated something" but i didn't find the problem

Comment: If you're just starting out with Chef I recommend going through the learn.chef.io tutorials. The poise-python upgrade is not a drop-in replacement, but it's close. There is an upgrade guide in the poise-python Readme.

Comment: in fact it tolds me when I tried vagrant up a strange error : Missing Cookbooks: default: Could not satisfy version constraints for: python which may have issues with upgrading , the file readme can help me?? because i don't have enough time to follow tutorials and search for it

Comment: If you don't have time for tutorials then no, I can't help you. Whatever you are trying to do will not work with Chef 13.

Comment: can't you help with the error that i faced? I think there is a problem between the use of 'python' and the new appellation poise-python

Comment: Yes, the issue is it's not a drop in replacement and everything using the old cookbook needs to be changed. It's a small change, but not nothing.

Comment: Basically your book is out of date and no longer works as is. You can try editing the vagrantfile to install Chef 12 instead but that requires work too so if you just want to follow the book you'll need a newer book.

Comment: so if I odify vagrantfile to install Chef 12 this will help me?

Comment: override.omnibus.chef_version = "11.6.0" in vagrant file is indicating the version of chef whcih will be installed???

Comment: That plugin isn't used anymore, https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/chef_common.html shows how to configure the version with modern Vagrant.